# Finding an unbounded harmonic function with prescribed boundary values

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I'm doing a practice problem on complex analysis taken from the qualifying exam of U of Washington and this question got me stuck for hours now:

Part 1: find a bounded real valued function $u$ that is continuous on $\{z\in\mathbb{C}|z\not=\pm1,\text{Im }z\geq 0,|z|\leq 1\}$ and harmonic on $\{z\in\mathbb{C}|\text{Im }z>0,|z|<1\}$ and $u(z)=3$ if $z\in(-1,1)$ and $u(z)=1$ if $|z|=1$, $\text{Im }z>0$.

Part 2: find an unbounded function with the same property.

The first part is easy, it is the imaginary part of $$\frac{4}{\pi}\log\bigg(\frac{1}{i}\frac{z-1}{z+1}\bigg)+i,$$ where the imaginary part of the log here is taken in $[0,2\pi).$ More explicitly, $$u(x,y)=\frac{4}{\pi}\arctan\frac{1-x^2-y^2}{2y}+1.$$ Here $\arctan$ is taken to be a function from $[0,\infty]$ to $[0,\pi/2]$.

But I have some trouble with the second part. I couldn't find an unbounded harmonic function with the same property. Can someone please help me? Thanks!

There is a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265650/finding-a-harmonic-function): but I do not understand why we can consider the function $z\mapsto-\frac{1}{2}(z+z^{-1})$ given there. It doesn't look right to me.

Comment: Use the Riemann mapping theorem to pull the problem back to the disk, then use the Poisson integral formula. If $+\infty$ is mapped to $1$ by the conformal map, then one way to do this is to add a harmonic function whose limiting distribution is a delta supported on $1$.

Comment: The easiest way is still to using the method in the accepted answer and the answer in my question though. Riemann mapping theorem+Caratheodory's theorem might work but will take way to long to compute in a qualifying exam.

Comment: Fair enough. I suppose it depends on whether the examiner would accept "the pushforward of this particular function under the conformal map whose existence is guaranteed by the Riemann mapping theorem" as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to solve part 2 it suffices to find a harmonic function $u$ in
$D = \{z \in \Bbb C \mid \operatorname{Im} z > 0,|z|<1\}$ which is continuous and equal to zero on $A = \overline D \setminus \{ -1, 1 \}$ and unbounded.

The function $f(z) = \left( \frac{z-1}{z+1} \right)^2$ maps $D$ conformally onto the lower half-plane and extends continuously to $A$, mapping the segment $(-1,1)$ and the upper half-circle to the positive and negative real axis, respectively.

$v(z) = \operatorname{Im}(z)$ is harmonic and unbounded in the lower half-plane, with boundary values zero except at $z=\infty$. Therefore
$$
 u(z) = \operatorname{Im}\left( \frac{z-1}{z+1} \right)^2
$$
has the desired properties.