# unbounded harmonic functions on bounded domain

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n,~n \geq3$ be a bounded domain with a smooth boundary. Does there exist any harmonic function $u \in C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ such that $u$ is bounded from below (or above), but not bounded from the other side?

A similar question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3755099/finding-an-unbounded-harmonic-function-with-prescribed-boundary-values), for $\mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{C}$ and $\Omega$ is the half-disk, which is different from this situation.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Comment: Sure, take $\Omega$ a ball and integrate the Poisson kernel against the Dirichlet distribution supported on a point $p$ on the boundary. The resulting harmonic function will tend to zero everywhere on the boundary, except that it will blow up as you tend to $p$. By minimum principle it's bounded below, but clearly not bounded above.